# DNS lookup not working properly in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I spin up a cluster with minikube then apply this dummy deployment/service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx-label
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx-label
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    run: nginx-label
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1234
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: nginx-label
```

Then I create a dummy curl pod to test internal network with the following

```
kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty
```

Inside that curl instance, I'm able to access the nginx with `$NGINX_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST:$NGINX_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT` or `nginx-service.default:1234`, but not `nginx-service:1234`, even though those pods belong to the same namespace.

```
ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pods --namespace=default
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t               1/1     Running   1          29m
nginx-deployment-58595d65fc-9ln25   1/1     Running   0          29m
nginx-deployment-58595d65fc-znkqp   1/1     Running   0          29m
```

Any idea what could cause this? Following is the nslookup result

```
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$ nslookup nginx-service
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      nginx-service
Address 1: 23.202.231.169 a23-202-231-169.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
Address 2: 23.217.138.110 a23-217-138-110.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$ nslookup nginx-service.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      nginx-service.default
Address 1: 10.103.69.73 nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$
```

Update: here's the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local attlocal.net
options ndots:5
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$
```

Comment: can u share /etc/resolv.conf from the nginx pod?

Comment: ```
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local attlocal.net
options ndots:5
[ root@curl-69c656fd45-d7w8t:/ ]$ 
```

Comment: Can you paste the output in proper format and edit question with this information ?

Comment: Sure. Post updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering on your question in comment.
Check following lines below the field `name` in nslookup file, for host `nginx-service` they are :

```
Name:      nginx-service
Address 1: 23.202.231.169 a23-202-231-169.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
Address 2: 23.217.138.110 a23-217-138-110.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
```

for  `nginx-service.default`:

```
Name:      nginx-service.default
Address 1: 10.103.69.73 nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

The flow is:

1. Executing command `nslookup`
2. Checking entrypoints(line below host with adress and hostname)
3. Comparing entrypoints and its domains to domain listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` file if it doesn't match this mean that we cannot reach specific host.

Your  `nginx-service`"hit" `a23-202-231-169.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com` **NOT**`nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local`.
`nginx-service.default`  "hit" `nginxservice.default.svc.cluster.local` as you said that is why curl is working.

`10.96.0.10` is the address of our system's Domain Name Server named `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`. This is the server your system is configured to use to translate domain names into IP addresses.

Speaking about the domain `deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com`
Akamai is a Content Delivery Network used by Symantec (and many other companies). Kubernetes is a cloud computing service used by a large number of companies as well for internet content. These services are essential for providing content when you visit certain websites, and for delivering things like product updates. It is normal to see connections to these sites when you visit certain other websites or have certain products, like Norton, installed. They essentially provide the servers needed to propagate large amounts of data to various regions of the world quickly while balancing internet traffic so that individual server locations are not overloaded..

> Hmm, sorry, not really...My question is that, based on the search
>   directive in  `/etc/resolv.conf`, if nginx-service.default is resolved
>   to nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local, so should nginx-service.
>   Did I miss anything?

**Answer:**

Keep in mind that:

1. Look firstly at `nslookup`
2. And then find match in `/etc/resolv.conf`

**Note:** In case you will do these steps vice versa, it won't work.

Reasons what may be the problem of wrong resolution of domain in nslookup are many - see: [dns-debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) . Try to execute command  `dig nginx-service`. Then interpret the output from this file to find the real problem. Because it is obvious that you cannot curl `nginx-service` (I have explained it above) but why nslookup shows different records for nameservers it is completely different question.

More information you can find here:  [nslookup](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/internet-and-networking/troubleshooting-dns-with-dig-and-nslookup), [akamai](https://community.norton.com/en/forums/strange-connections-deploystaticakamaitechnologiescom-why).

Comment: Really appreciate your very detailed explanation! But I just don't follow the last part...I do have `default.svc.cluster.local` in my `/etc/resolv.conf`. So my understanding is that if I search `nginx-service`, it will hit `nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local` which would be the same if I search `nginx-service.default`. Also I'm using the default name server from k8s, so I don't even know how it got those akamaitechnologies.com records...

Comment: Can you check updates? I have edit my answer.  Hopefully I clarified your doubts.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, not really...My question is that, based on the search directive in `/etc/resolv.conf`, if nginx-service.default is resolved to nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local, so should nginx-service. Did I miss anything?

Comment: And just to add more context: I just spin up a Ubuntu18 VM in my laptop, setup minikube and deploy some pods as a service. Based on k8s doc, <service> and <service>.<namespace> (nginx-service and nginx-service.default here) should result to the same destination. So I don't know why the built-in name server is behaving like this unexpected...

Comment: I have edited my answer to more precisive. Can you check updates ?